# How to Get User Profile details by using accesstoken (tokenId)?

Tags: java, oauth, google-oauth, google-api-java-client, google-developers-console

I tried to get the profile details of the google user, I already got an access token by using the refresh token now I want to get the details of the user.
I have no idea what I have to pass in the `idTokenString` parameter, Whether I have to pass Access Token of the user in this case?

I used the following code

```
  GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new GsonFactory()).setAudience(Collections.singletonList("My Client ID is provided here")).build();
  GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(idTokenString);
  if (idToken != null) {
     Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();  
     String userId = payload.getSubject();
     System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);
  }
```

Comment: Id token is authentication (sign in)  your want authorization (oauth2).   Please edit your question and include [example]  I need to see how you are authorizing this

Comment: To get User profile information the best best way is to go though the [People api](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/java)

Comment: I want to use oauth library ,In this case I need to know want kind of idtokenString we have to pass into verify method. Is there any possibilities to get idtokenString manually?


 GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new GsonFactory())
                .setAudience(Collections.singletonList("My client Id "))
                .build();
String idToken1 = "idtokenString";

Comment: I want to use oauth library ,In this case I need to know want kind of idtokenString we have to pass into verify method. Is there any possibilities to get idtokenString manually? Here is my code:
GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new GsonFactory()) .setAudience(Collections.singletonList("Myclient Id ")).build();
String idToken1 = "idtokenString";
   GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(idToken1);
 if (idToken != null) {
            Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();
            String userId = payload.getSubject();

Answer (score 1):

> I have no idea what I have to pass in the idTokenString parameter, Whether I have to pass Access Token of the user in this case?

No you pass the id token as the method states.

[GoogleIdTokenVerifier.java#L163](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/blob/main/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleIdTokenVerifier.java#L35)

```
   /**
   * Verifies that the given ID token is valid using the cached public keys.
   *
   * <p>It verifies:
   *
   * <ul>
   *   <li>The RS256 signature, which uses RSA and SHA-256 based on the public keys downloaded from
   *       the public certificate endpoint.
   *   <li>The current time against the issued at and expiration time (allowing for a 5 minute clock
   *       skew).
   *   <li>The issuer is {@code "accounts.google.com"} or {@code "https://accounts.google.com"}.
   * </ul>
   *
   * @param googleIdToken Google ID token
   * @return {@code true} if verified successfully or {@code false} if failed
   */
```

The method takes a google Id token.

An `id_token` is the result of a authentication > signin request.  using openid connect.

An `access token` is the result of an authorization request using OAuth2.

If you want to get user profile data with an access token after a user has authorized your application to access their profile data. You would go thought the people api.

If you want to verify your authencation of the user you use the id token use `GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder` and pass the id token from the authentication response.

I suspect you are confusing two different things. authentication (id token) and authorization (access token).